# How can I make an argument on action function equal to the current date on yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I want `$startdate` to equal the current date dynamically.

This is my code:

```
public function actionNextcourses($startdate = '2016-04-02' )
{
    $nextcourses = Courses::find()->where('start_date > :startdate', [':startdate'=>$startdate])->all();
    return $this->render('nextcourses', ['nextcourses'=>$nextcourses]);
}
public function actionPrevcourses($startdate = '2016-04-02')
{
    $prevcourses = Courses::find()->where('start_date < :startdate', [':startdate'=>$startdate])->all();
    return $this->render('prevcourses', ['prevcourses'=>$prevcourses]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve using null default value:

```
public function actionNextcourses($startdate = null )
{
    if($startDate == null) $startDate = date('Y-m-d');

    $nextcourses = Courses::find()->where('start_date > :startdate', [':startdate'=>$startdate])->all();
    return $this->render('nextcourses', ['nextcourses'=>$nextcourses]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not allow to set default dynamic values for function arguments.

Comment: thanks @FabrizioCaldarelli.
It worked but what is the useful of if else statement here ?! 
I deleted it and it worked properly.